# If else sas data step

Tags: sas, datastep

I need to write the logic

```
If y=1 then y=1;
else y=y+x and z=5;
```

Everything is normal but the second part of statement (and x=5) does not working.

Comment: What did you expect `and x=5` to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do this:

```
if y^=1 then do;
  y=y+x;
  z=5;
end;
```

Comment: yeap, thanks Tom! Its the end of the day) sorry for my moronic questions)